# Why doesn't sprintf() output anything?

Tags: php, printf

I've never used these functions before but after reading a lot about sprintf(), I decided I should get to know it.

So I went ahead and did the following.

```
function currentDateTime() {
  list($micro, $Unixtime) = explode(" ",microtime());
  $sec= $micro + date("s", $Unixtime);
  $sec = mb_ereg_replace(sprintf('%d', $sec), "", ($micro + date("s", $Unixtime)));
  return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $Unixtime).$sec;
}

sprintf(currentDateTime());
```

It prints nothing. Using the printf() function on the other hand:

```
printf(currentDateTime());
```

It prints the result just fine. So what's the difference between these 2 functions and how do I properly use the sprintf() function?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`sprintf()` returns a string, `printf()` displays it.

The following two are equal:

```
printf(currentDateTime());
print sprintf(currentDateTime());
```

Comment: I remember it by thinking '**silent** `printf()`' :)

Comment: @deed02392, Isn't that `s` representing "string"?

Comment: No, because `printf()` outputs a string too.

Answer (score 15):

`sprintf()` prints the result to a string. `printf()` prints it to standard output ie:

```
printf(currentDateTime());
```

is equivalent to:

```
echo sprintf(currentDateTime());
```

Answer (score 6):

sprintf() returns a string while printf() outputs a string. So you'd have to do something like the following:

```
function currentDateTime() {
  list($micro, $Unixtime) = explode(" ",microtime());
  $sec= $micro + date("s", $Unixtime);
  $sec = mb_ereg_replace(sprintf('%d', $sec), "", ($micro + date("s", $Unixtime)));
  return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $Unixtime).$sec;
}

$output = sprintf(currentDateTime());
printf($output);
```

http://www.php.net/sprintf

http://www.php.net/printf