# Printf and sprintf where exactly used in php? give one example?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [PHP sprintf() and printf() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021743/php-sprintf-and-printf-functions)
>   [Why use sprintf function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386593/why-use-sprintf-function-in-php)

Printf and sprintf where exactly used in php? give one example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) have many options to format your output string. This SO answer will help you more:

[Why use sprintf function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386593/why-use-sprintf-function-in-php/1386607#1386607)

Answer (score 3):

`printf` function in php is used to output a formatted string

For example:

```
<?php
$format = 'I have %d questions to %s';
printf($format, 2, 'answer');
?>
```

This will output as follows: 
`I have 2 questions to answer`

---

`sprintf` function in php is used to return a formatted string.

For Example:

```
<?php
$format = 'I have %d questions to %s';
$a_string = sprintf($format, 2, 'answer');
echo $a_string; 
?>
```

This will output as follows: `I have 2 questions to answer`

---

In the second example `sprintf` function returns a formatted string and gets stored into the variable `$a_string`.